# What upvote/ downvote , question/ answer ratios do responsible senior users have?

Tags: discussion

I was just looking at my ratios. I'm sure one answer would be, "whatever the circumstances at the time dictated."  But would anyone care to share or offer guideline?

Comment: Relevant: http://data.stackexchange.com/christianity%20stack%20exchange/query/13431/compare-me-against-the-most-frequent-voters

Comment: Thanks for triggering me on this. I hardly every downvoted but since reading this I've done it much more, when I think it is warranted. My ratio is about 1:15 (downvote:upvote).

Answer (score 5):

A few thoughts in addition to Mason's ratio.

- Upvote/Downvote  - This is a very personal choice, but it's also public. For reference my ration is about 13:1. I don't really try to maintain any kind of ratio though. I up vote things I find useful and down vote things that I don't.
- Question/Answer vote - This we actually have a bit more insight on. Again the number are public and I'll share mine for reference: 8:5 (Q/A). The little bit of guidance we're given on Question/answer votes are in the following mechanical constructs:

  - The Electorate Badge (600 question votes, 25% of total must be on questions)
  - Number of votes/day (40, 10 reserved for questions only).
  - A reminder alert when it's been a while when you've voted on questions

This seems to indicate that SE really wants to incentivize question voting in a real mechnaical way. It's easy to fall into a habit of just upvoting answers and forget to vote on questions. That said, there isn't an ideal ratio. I find the best way to vote is to use the site normally and upvote content you find useful, questions or answers. Again, it's OK and even recommended to be intentional about upvoting lots of questions, but there isn't an ideal ratio here.

Comment: I upvote questions if they are on topic and I can conceptualize them being useful for a long time to come.

Answer (score 2):

I was rather surprised at my ranking - I assumed my 10:1 (up:down) ratio was really soft.  It looks like mine is about, average, however.

- I hate downvoting answers.  Its costs me rep!  But it makes me think twice too :)
- I do downvote questions that are off-topic or just silly. Quality matters!
- I tend to vote down more often when I'm not on an even 5 or 0.  I like my round numbers!

Comment: Yes me too. I hate spending the rep, but there is no rep penalty for downvoting questions and if it stinks and they haven't gotten hit hard enough for it, I quickly downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Just had a look.  Right now, my up:down ratio is about 5:1 on Meta.Christianity, where downvotes are more strongly encouraged for marking bad ideas for the site, and 28:1 on Christianity.

Answer (score 1):

Although irresponsible and not senior (just coming to my first year 20 October), I feel talkative.

#### Meandering personal comments not addressing the question

I almost never down vote posts (3:673 down:up votes on main; 0:145 on meta [this surprises me given the lesser weight--more agreement than usefulness--and absence of reputation penalty]). If a post is at -2 or lower, it hardly seems appropriate to down vote further (unless the post is so bad that flagging would be more appropriate). Even if it is at -1, I feel some hesitancy to pile on. On the other hand, I am hesitant to be the first to down vote (unless the post is very bad, when I should probably be flagging the post--it looks like all of the posts I down voted were deleted [or were questions] since I have no reputation loss from my 3 down votes).

Not unlike with answering, if I hesitate enough others will almost always provide.

Another discouragement to down voting for me is the feeling that a meaningful comment should be made to explain the down vote. *One* of the reasons I have not reviewed many posts is that I find making a meaningful comment difficult. (I have difficulty writing "Welcome" followed by strong criticism. Just linking the about page seems very weak, especially for answers [the about page is very question-oriented]. As someone who is easily discouraged, I would not want to discourage someone else, but "this post might not be salvageable, but please post again when you can provide a polite, concise, and well supported answer" does not seem very inviting. Writing "while this post has some issues, I encourage you to become an active and constructive part of this community" seems incomplete or disingenuous, and adding "by following our community standards" might work. [Perhaps I need to write some boilerplate/templates for down vote and some issues comments to satisfy accuracy *and* politeness.])

I have probably increased both my frequency of voting and perhaps my relative frequency of voting for questions since beginning to seek the Electorate badge. (Participation in the start of space.se also seems to have increased my voting rate elsewhere.) My current 231:445 question:answer voting ratio seems unusually high. The revival of some old questions *might* have some impact on the ratio since some fairly good older questions are less highly scored than their answers and less than 10 (Nice Answer). I also tend to view questions before they have been highly up voted, so I am more likely to up vote a decent question (it is easier [for me] to up vote an okay question to 2 or 3 than a fairly decent question to 10).

Questions also receive more benefit of the doubt; even some impoliteness might be attributed to ignorance (which is why one asks questions). Questions also have a different mechanism for handling duplication of content and such duplication is not as obvious. Down-voting a question might feel a bit like discouraging curiosity (even though some questions seem to fit the "does not show any research effort"--yet sometimes search query formulations obvious to one who can answer the question might not be obvious to one asking the question); I have become more willing to score weak questions at 1 or 2.

(Based on the title/hover-text on the up vote control, everyone who views a meaningful and well-formed question ["useful and clear"] whose answer cannot be found trivially with a web search ["shows research effort"] should up vote that question. Likewise, almost every half-way decent answer could be counted as "useful" if measured in isolation. Most viewers seem to be making a judgment based partially on the current score of a post [and for answers based on other answers].)

(It is more difficult to up vote an answer [especially if posted later] that adds no significant content beyond what is available in another answer, even if the answer contains useful content if judged in isolation. The fact that I tend to wait a little longer before up-voting answers further reduces the probability of up-voting an answer.)

(I am also excessively badge-aware and recognize the 10 and 25 score boundaries. I am more likely to up vote a post scored at 10 than one scored at 9.)

While my behavior is probably atypical, my motives are probably not unique (being not common or not typically as prominent can account for their being atypical), so this post might provide some more general insight.

#### Some Possible Guidelines (i.e., addressing the question)

As [wax eagle points out](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2223), SE is designed to encourage voting on questions. (He did not mention the fact that down voting questions does not have the 1 reputation point cost that down voting answers has.) While part of this is probably meant to counter the greater difficulty of evaluating a question in isolation (even a single answer has the immediate context of the question; a question's value tends to use the context of the community/site in general), part of the motivation may be to encourage non-bad questions.

While *good* questions encourage expert participation, decent questions draw more traffic and retain the interest of visitors so that they are more likely to ask questions and even to develop the skills and knowledge to ask good (and even expert-worthy) questions (perhaps even providing some good answers by specific research [being invested in the site] or accumulated knowledge [from this site and the additional reading it encourages]). Rewarding a decent question with a score of 1 or 2 provides an incentive to that poster and to other posters to ask at least decent questions. Further up-voting can help more time-constrained potential answerers address high-value questions and reward quality content.

Up-voting unusually good questions is also important in providing an incentive for good questions, in making question value more apparent (both to those who might ask a question and to those filtering questions to answer or even just read [higher-scored questions probably tend to draw even more views and even reading questions and their answers is part of community involvement]). To accomplish these goals, obviously *score* **should** be considered and not just whether a question meets the requirements of being useful (clear and researched).

Since badges are provided for scores of 10 and 25, these scores can reasonably help inform up-voting choices. Moving a score from 9 to 10 *is* making a more significant statement than moving it from 10 to 11 (the badge factor *and* the digit count factor).

While seriously problematic questions should be flagged, it is also important to discourage poor questions. Any not-decent question should (ideally) receive a comment to explain why it was not up-voted at least once. In my opinion, a question should be down-voted if it is very unclear (or unclear with no response to a comment asking for clarification), it is very off-topic--i.e., difficult to salvage--or off-topic with no effort shown to improve it, or it is very poorly presented (or poorly presented with no improvement after comments).

(Obviously, if every question worthy of a 0 score should [ideally] have a comment, a down-voted question should have a comment.)

Bad questions tend to be destructive by encouraging more bad questions and by discouraging community involvement (reading questions and answers [which is important in developing a sense of community--listening is important], posting decent questions, and posting decent answers).

Similar guidelines would seem to apply for answers. However, **I** would suggest that voting on answers should be modestly more negatively biased. I.e., answers should be held to a higher standard.

Using a higher standard might compensate for some of the comparison bias (while a question might be perceived more positively with a good answer and so receive inappropriate up-voting, it is easier to see that a decent answer actually answers the question), but such is also important because answers are answers ("stupid question" vs. "stupid answer").

(I would also claim that *some* reputation-based bias can be reasonably applied in voting. Users that should know better are more deserving of down votes for bad posts. Experienced and higher-reputation users are also less likely to be discouraged by lower post scores. However, it is also important to guard against an anti-wealth bias [or the opposing halo effect], so any such weaker encouragement should be relatively small.)

The up vote to down vote ratio probably depends significantly on how frequently one visits the site and views questions. Questions worthy of a down vote, will usually receive a -1 or -2 score fairly quickly and this community (and perhaps SE generally) seems to frown on piling on down votes. It seems to take a little longer for a question worthy of a score of 5 or more to reach its "proper" scoring and an occasional act of generosity to a new user with a decent-ish post may justify a late up vote for a 0 [or low-] scored question or answer.

(Of the top 8 users in yearly reputation, the down:up vote ratios are: 1:10.7, 1:2.36, 1:5.24, 1:10.7, 1:9.71, 1:10.9, 1:2.61, 1:27.0. The variation seems to be substantial, but the median is around 1:10. My *guess* would be that the two frequent down vote outliers [Caleb and Narnian] come from high self-confidence in their judgments [i.e., not afraid to down vote and do so justly] and frequent visiting of the site and viewing of active questions [reading posts before others have voted on them])

With respect to the ratio of question and answer votes, the 1:3 ratio may be a decent **general** guideline. If the ratio is more like 1:5, it is likely that one is not voting on questions enough (though it is possible that one usually comes to the questions late after they have been "properly" scored but a later answer [or edit] has not yet been fully up-voted). (With down votes, late answers might be more likely to be worthy of a down vote.) If the ratio is close to 1:0.5, it is likely that one is not voting on enough answers (though is is possible that the questions that you view are hard/good questions which do not receive many good [or horrible] answers--titles, scores, and partial previews can also filter question viewing--or that one is often viewing questions before any answers were posted and not re-viewing them later).

(Of the top 8 reputation earners for the year, the Q:A vote ratios are: 1:1.59, 1:1.47, 1:1.67, 1:0.75, 1:0.83, 1:1.93, 1:1.84, and 1:2.20. This would imply that a even a 1:3 ratio might be pushing into the danger zone and that something closer to 1:1.6 might be a reasonable target.)

#### Conclusion

In general, I would suggest that a 1:10 down:up vote ratio and a 1:1.6 question:answer vote ratio would be good targets. However, these ratios seem to be very weak tools for evaluating one's voting. Not only is there significant variation among high reputation users, but there are also reasonable causes that would lead to voting patterns different from such targets.

I would also assert that some diversity in personality and attitude is good and should influence voting patterns. While my 1:224 down:up vote ratio is irresponsible (especially since I visit frequently enough to encounter new bad posts and have been around long enough to understand the site's values), even a 1:50 ratio might be okay for a less frequent visitor (so most posts are old enough to have been voted on by others reducing the need for down votes), especially for a user whose personality is oriented more toward encouragement. (Being a bad citizen in one area also does not make one entirely useless to the community.)

---

Eek! That was one extremely long post for the limited content post!

Comment: You're absolutely right that the motivation for encouraging question voting is to encourage non-bad question asking